# How I can add XML prolog in Groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy

I need add xml prolog (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`, see [xml-prolog](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp)) in xml file: 
Source:

```
<xml>
    <el>value</el>
    <el>value</el>
</xml>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<xml>
        <el>value</el>
        <el>value</el>
    </xml>
```

How I can it in Groovy?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use replaceAll():

```
xml = '''<xml>
    <el>value</el>
    <el>value</el>
</xml>
'''

xml2 = xml.replaceAll("<xml>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<xml>")

println xml2
```

Answer (score -1):

Also it can do with **DOMBuilder**

```
String ​xml = "<xml><el>value</el><el>value</el></xml>"
​​​​​def reader = new StringReader(xml)
def doc = DOMBuilder.parse(reader)
def records = doc.documentElement
records​
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xml>
  <el>value</el>
  <el>value</el>
</xml>
```